# getting error 'Keyword "optional" is not a valid type constructor' in terraform with terraform version ">= 0.15"

Tags: apache-kafka, terraform

In the current terraform pipeline, I am passing topics as a list

```
locals {
  test_topics = [
    {
      name                      = "topic1"
      is_public                 = true
      version                   = 1
      is_cleanup_policy_compact = true
      max_message_bytes         = "-1"
      partition_count = 3
    },
    {
      name                      = "topic2"
      is_public                 = true
      version                   = 1
      is_cleanup_policy_compact = true
      max_message_bytes         = "-1"
      partition_count = 4
    },
    {
      name                      = "topic3"
      is_public                 = true
      version                   = 1
      is_cleanup_policy_compact = true
      max_message_bytes         = "-1"
      partition_count = 5     
    },
    {
      name                      = "topic4"
      is_public                 = true
      version                   = 1
      is_cleanup_policy_compact = true
      max_message_bytes         = "-1"
    },
    {
      name                      = "topic5"
      is_public                 = true
      version                   = 1
      is_cleanup_policy_compact = true
      max_message_bytes         = "-1"
      partition_count = 5
    }
  ]
}

# example create topic it automatically assigns READ WRITE access to the service account and READ access to all PUBLIC topics
module "test_topics" {
  source = "../kafka_topic"
  topics = "${local.test_topics}"
  environment     = var.environment
  data_domain     = var.data_domain
  service_account = var.service_account
}
```

and declaring variables in child modules like below

```
variable "topics" {
  type        = list(object({
    name = string
    is_public = bool
    is_cleanup_policy_compact = bool
    version = number
    max_message_bytes = number
    partition_count = number
}))
  description = "list of topics with their configuration"
  default = null
}
```

and in child main.tf we are creating the topics using following code

```
resource "kafka_topic" "topic" {
  count              = length(var.topics)
  name               = "${lookup(var.topics[count.index], "is_public") ? "public" :"private"}_${var.environment}_${var.data_domain}_${lookup(var.topics[count.index], "name")}_${lookup(var.topics[count.index], "version")}"
  partitions         = lookup(var.topics[count.index], "partition_count") == null ? 6 : "${lookup(var.topics[count.index], "partition_count")}"
  replication_factor = 3
  config = {
    "cleanup.policy" = lookup(var.topics[count.index], "is_cleanup_policy_compact") ? "compact" : "delete"
    "max.message.bytes" =  lookup(var.topics[count.index], "max_message_bytes") != -1 ? "${lookup(var.topics[count.index], "max_message_bytes")}" : 1000012
  }
}
```

but when running terraform plan I am getting following exception

attribute "partition_count" is required.

Note : I also used partition_count = optional(number) in declaring the variable in variable.tf (to keep that attribute as a optional field) but getting following error

Keyword "optional" is not a valid type constructor

as it might be due to the terraform version currently I am using which is ">= 0.12" but when I tried with the ">= 0.15" version, got the same error 'Keyword "optional" is not a valid type constructor' error.
Is there any way I can fix this issue?

Comment: Which provider is this?

Comment: To answer the question for the second attempt: `optional` was experimental prior to 1.3 and did not exist before 0.14, and so you would indeed need to enable it as an experimental feature: https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/v1.1.x/expressions/type-constraints#experimental-optional-object-type-attributes

Comment: Mongey/kafka provider currently we are using

Comment: Which version of the provider?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any optional attributes in any type constraint you've shown in the question, so I think there must be more to your configuration than what you've included. Please extend your question to include the rest of your configuration, and also the entire error message you saw _exactly as Terraform printed it_, including all of the source location information and summary.

Comment: Optional attributes are a very recent Terraform feature so you'll need to upgrade to Terraform v1.3.0 or later to use a module that includes them. However, it isn't clear from your question exactly _what_ is using optional attributes in your case.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add this:

```
terraform {
  experiments = [module_variable_optional_attrs]
}
```